# How to throw an Exception if file on ftp is locked? Spring DSL

Tags: ftp, apache-camel, camel-ftp

My route is polling from endpoint
`ftp://localhost:21/folder?username=user&password=password&delay=15s&move=processed&moveFailed=error&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&passiveMode=true.`
If I just add `readLock=rename`, Camel will ignore troublesome file and leave it in folder.

How to implement camel behavior so that if file is still being locked by somebody **after** `readLockTimeout` or `n` attempts, Camel will not skip the file, but throw an Exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this can be established by implementing a custom ReadLockStrategy (the interface is `GenericFileExclusiveReadLockStrategy`)

You can set the custom strategy using the option `exclusiveReadLockStrategy` (see [File2](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) component options).

P.S. Maybe its best to override one of the strategies provided out of the box, `FileLockExclusiveReadLockStrategy` for instance. All you need then is to override the `acquireExclusiveReadLock()` method to throw an exception when its super returns false.